# how to deep copy a vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class Container with a data member.

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function> > Functions;
```

I want to do a deep copy in my copy constructor , how can i do a deep copy of std::unique_ptr.

Comment: I recommend you look at the smart pointers from an *ownership* perspective. A unique pointer can have only one single owner, and a shared pointer can have multiple owners. Using that perspective, it makes no sense to copy an object owned through a unique pointer.

Comment: @Some programmer dude i want both of them to have different ownership of their data.

Comment: Unless `Sum_Function` is a polymorphic base class (and for "functions" and callable objects there are better solutions than polymorphic base classes since C++11) then I suggest you simply use a vector of objects (i.e. `std::vector<Sum_Function>`) instead, and follow [the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: `virtual` `Clone` method is generally the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function>> copiedFunctions;
std::for_each(Functions.begin(), Functions.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function> f){
  copiedFunctions.push_back(std::make_unique<Sum_Function>(*f));
}));
```

This implies that `Sum_Function` has a copy constructor, of course.

Comment: Just a sidenote, this is not how one is supposed to use the `for_each()` (since it has a return value if no `execution policy` is chosen), `range-based for` or `transform()` is more suitable pick.

Comment: Modifying a **copy** of the resulting vector is mostly pointless. -> capture by reference.

Answer (score 3):

If `Sum_Function` is the concrete type that you want to copy:

```
#include <algorithm>

Container(const Container& other) : Functions(other.Functions.size())
{
   std::transform(other.Functions.cbegin(), other.Functions.cend(), Functions.begin(),
       [](const auto& uPtr){ return uPtr ? std::make_unique<Sum_Function>(*uPtr) : nullptr; });
}
```

Otherwise (e.g. when `Sum_Function` is an abstract base class), you need a `virtual` factory member function `Sum_Function::clone()` that should be invoked in the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

As you can't make a copy of `std::unique_ptr`, you need to manually copy all the elements, I think the best approach would be `std::transform`.

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function>> copy;
copy.reserve(Functions.size());

std::transform(Functions.cbegin(), Functions.cend(), std::back_inserter(copy),
               [](const std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function&> ptr) { return std::make_unique<Sum_Function>(*ptr); }
              );
```

This code assumes that `Sum_Function` has a copy constructor.